# How to login to gmail account and read a mail in protractor not using the browser

Tags: javascript, email, protractor

I have a scenario which I need to login to a gmail account and read the content or the message. Then need to get a URL from that message. I can do this using a browser in protractor. But the issue is that gmail account enabled the 2FA. I have achieved this using the core Selenium which has jar files to log in to the gmail account using IMAP protocol.

Can someone please give me a good solution?

Comment: Please add how you achieved the above using the IMAP protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You can read emails from Gmail inside protractor tests using `mail-listener2` npm package. Check the below example code.

**mailListener.ts**

```
const MailListenerClient = require("mail-listener2");
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;
export class MailListener {

  public mailListener:any;

  constructor() {
      this.mailListener = new MailListenerClient({
          username: "username@gmail.com",
          password: "password",
          host: "imap.gmail.com",
          port: 993,
          tls: true,
          mailbox: "INBOX",
          searchFilter: ["UNSEEN", ["FROM", "fromemail@gmail.com"],["SUBJECT","subject of the email"]], 
          /*it will search for are "unseen" mail send from "fromemail@gmail.com" with subject "fromemail@gmail.com"*/
          connTimeout: 10000,
          authTimeout: 5000,
          markSeen: true,
          mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
          attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
          attachmentOptions: {directory: "attachments/"},
          debug : console.log
       });
   }

  init() {
      this.mailListener.start();
  }

  close() {
     this.mailListener.stop();
  }


  getLinkFromEmail() {
      var self = this;
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          self.mailListener.on("mail", function (mail) {
              /*simpleParser is used to convert string to HTML format*/
              simpleParser(mail.eml).then(function (parsedEmail) {
                  var html = parsedEmail.html;
                  /* cheerio is used to write query on parsed HTML content
                   * refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio 
                   */
                  resolve(cheerio.load(html)("a").attr("href"));
              });
          });

          self.mailListener.on("error", function (err) {
             reject(err);
          });
      });
  }

}
```

**test.ts**

```
import {MailListener} from "mailListner";

describe("Read email from gmail using imap", function () {
  let mailListener = new MailListener();

  beforeAll(function(){
    mailListener.init();
  });

  afterAll(function(){
    mailListener.close();
  })

  it("Test email recieved",function(){
       let urlFromEmail =  mailListener.getLinkFromEmail();

       /*Perform some action on UI that triggers email.(Just for example im doing it)*/
       element(by.id("email")).sendKeys("email@gmail.com");
       element(by.buttonText("Send Email")).click();
       expect(urlFromEmail).toEqual("some link");
    })
});
```

I have written the code in typescript and hope you can rewrite the same in javascript. Let me know if this is clear or do I need to add more details to the code.

Comment: On the return new Promise line in mailListener.ts I am getting 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. from Angular IDE 2017, though tsc seems happy to compile it

Answer (score 0):

One of the best practice is to use Gmail API. Take a look at [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/)